# putting a square or circle image in line path in google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, line

i've drawn a line-path in Google map using javascript and gps co-ordinates.

can anyone please tell me how to put a circle or square at the end of the line-path drawn in Google map.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nidhish31589/wLeBh/)

my code is as shown below

```
function initialize(){
       var center= new google.maps.LatLng(10.012552,76.327043);
       var myOptions = {
                zoom: 16,
                center: center,
                mapTypeControl: true,
                mapTypeControlOptions: {style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU},
                navigationControl: true,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
       }     
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

      var polylineCoordinates = [
            new google.maps.LatLng(10.013566,76.331549),
            new google.maps.LatLng(10.013566,76.331463),
            new google.maps.LatLng(10.013503,76.331313),
            new google.maps.LatLng(10.013482,76.331205),
            new google.maps.LatLng(10.013419,76.330926),
new google.maps.LatLng(10.013334,76.330712),
new google.maps.LatLng(10.013313,76.330411),
new google.maps.LatLng(10.013292,76.330175),
new google.maps.LatLng(10.013228,76.329854),
new google.maps.LatLng(10.013144,76.329553),
new google.maps.LatLng(10.013059,76.329296),
new google.maps.LatLng(10.012996,76.329017),
new google.maps.LatLng(10.012869,76.328802),
new google.maps.LatLng(10.012785,76.328545),
new google.maps.LatLng(10.012700,76.328223),
new google.maps.LatLng(10.012679,76.328030),
new google.maps.LatLng(10.012658,76.327837),
new google.maps.LatLng(10.012637,76.327600),
new google.maps.LatLng(10.012573,76.327322),
new google.maps.LatLng(10.012552,76.327043),

      ];
      var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
          path: polylineCoordinates,
          strokeColor: '#FF3300',
          strokeOpacity: 2.0,
          strokeWeight: 5,
          editable: false
      });

      polyline.setMap(map);    
}
initialize();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may create an [Icon](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#ComplexIcons)   at the given position `polylineCoordinates[polylineCoordinates.length-1]`

[**http://jsfiddle.net/wLeBh/5/**](http://jsfiddle.net/wLeBh/5/)

Comment: sir can you please tell me how to download the html from jsfiddle.net

Comment: right-click on this link: http://jsfiddle.net/wLeBh/5/show/ , and choose *save as...*